# Calculate p-values from t.tests on rows

Tags: r

I tried to calculate p-values with the following codes and got the following error.

```
control <- c("TMT126", "TMT127N", "TMT128N")
condition1 <- c("TMT128C", "TMT129C")

my.pvalue2 <- function(x){
  pValue <- -log10(t.test(x[condition1],x[control])$p.value)
  return(pValue)
}

df.test.1 <- df.test %>% 
  mutate(
    `minus Log10(p-value:condition1)` = apply(df.test,1, my.pvalue2)
  )
```

**Error message:**

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `minus Log10(p-value:condition1)`. x missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed i Input `minus Log10(p-value:condition1)` is `apply(df.test, 1, my.pvalue2)`. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Here is my data frame:

```
structure(list(Mod.sites = c("O00444_41;O00444_45", "O60674_882", 
"Q00534_147", "Q00535_128", "Q00535_33", "Q00536_194", "Q07002_173;Q00537_221", 
"Q01813_688", "Q02779_125", "Q04759_409"), Gene.names = c("PLK4;PLK4", 
"JAK2", "CDK6", "CDK5", "CDK5", "CDK16", "CDK18;CDK17", "PFKP", 
"MAP3K10", "PRKCQ"), TMT126 = c(3288.072, 13709.112, 7385.65, 
8745.428, 2340613.834, 80135.384, 80983.353, 103455.239, 17458.005, 
2613.544), TMT127N = c(3309.906, 13417.091, 7869.857, 9373.869, 
2465534.452, 87019.964, 90631.048, 114170.91, 16610.071, 2166.909
), TMT128N = c(3548.599, 11629.91, 4928.31, 6907.338, 1870749.67, 
68310.079, 66666.097, 98771.109, 11859.635, 2857.691), TMT128C = c(2604.707, 
10592.479, 7377.602, 7770.825, 2486390.256, 87029.508, 85519.165, 
125000.311, 17476.655, 2342.452), TMT129N = c(2788.393, 15370.127, 
7735.087, 9064.821, 2562044.041, 92699.625, 92224.515, 136098.104, 
16956.515, 3926.526), TMT129C = c(2444.359, 11317.83, 6367.838, 
7646.522, 2127848.806, 72815.465, 68049.111, 110220.905, 14452.069, 
2634.257), TMT130N = c(2526.87, 13526.895, 5884.736, 9009.732, 
2352356.375, 81032.103, 81832.598, 118737.643, 18469.613, 2615.477
), TMT130C = c(3032.719, 14006.2, 8143.08, 9582.292, 2505646.114, 
75513.63, 64489.184, 119498.654, 17711.228, 3766.643), TMT131 = c(2608.501, 
13551.762, 6112.602, 8897.896, 2738069.654, 84153.628, 75770.329, 
120319.927, 18680.595, 4309.018)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: The `control` and `condition1` number of elements are different.  Are you doing pairwise?

Comment: @akrun I am considering doing a two-sample unequal variance test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `apply()`, R converts the data frame into a matrix, which coerces all of the columns to be of the same type, which makes your numeric values into characters.  The simplest solution is probably to exclude the first two columns when running `apply()`, as below:

```r
df.test.1 <- df.test %>% 
   mutate(
    `minus Log10(p-value:condition1)` = apply(df.test[-(1:2)],1, my.pvalue2)
)
```

Alternatively you could use `as.numeric(x[condition1])`, `as.numeric(x[control])` in `my.pvalue2`.